# how to count the biggest consecutive occurences of substring in string?

Tags: python

I'm doing an exercise ([cs50 - DNA](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2021/psets/6/dna/)) where I have to count specific consecutive substrings (STRS) mimicking DNA sequences, I'm finding myself overcomplicating my code and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to proceed.

I have a list of substrings:

`strs = ['AGATC', 'AATG', 'TATC']`

And a String with a random sequence of letters:

`AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAGAAAAGAGTAAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATTAATGGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG`

I want to count the biggest consecutive substrings that match each strs.

So:

- `'AGATC'` - AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGG**AGATCAGATCAGATCAGATC**TATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAGAAAAGAGTAAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATTAATGGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG
- `'AATG'` - AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAGAAAAGAGTAAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATT**AATG**GAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG
- `'TATC'` - AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATC**TATCTATCTATCTATCTATC**AGAAAAGAGTAAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATTAATGGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG

resulting in `[4, 1, 5]`

(Note that this isn't the best example since there are no random repeating patterns scatered around but I think it illustrates what I'm looking for)

I know that I should be something of the likes of `re.match(rf"({strs}){2,}", string)` because `str.count(strs)` will give me **ALL consecutive and non consecutive items**.

My code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv
import sys
from cs50 import get_string

# sys.exit to terminate the program
# sys.exit(2) UNIX default for wrong args
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("Usage: python dna.py data.csv sequence.txt")
    sys.exit(2)

# open file, make it into a list, get STRS, remove header
with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as database:
    data = list(csv.reader(database))
    STRS = data[0]
    data.pop(0)

# remove "name" so only thing remaining are STRs
STRS.pop(0)

# open file to compare agaist db
with open(sys.argv[2], "r") as seq:
    sequence = seq.read()

sequenceCount = []

# for each STR count the occurences
# sequence.count(s) returns all
for s in STRS:
    sequenceCount.append(sequence.count(s))

print(STRS)
print(sequenceCount)

"""
sequenceCount = {}

# for each STR count the occurences
for s in STRS:
    sequenceCount[s] = sequence.count(s)

for line in data:
    print(line)
    for item in line[1:]:
        continue


# rf"({STRS}){2,}"
"""
```

Comment: @MiguelP so I am right in saying that you only want to find "consecutive" (back2back) matches of the sequence, not a single one or two that exist in "isolation" in the dna strand?

Comment: @OmarAlSuwaidi Yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression for finding repeating strings is like `r"(AGATC)+"`.

For example,

```py
import re

sequence = "AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAGAAAAGAGTAAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATTAATGGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG"
pattern = "AGATC"

r = re.search(r"({})+".format(pattern), sequence)

if r:
    print("start at", r.start())
    print("end at", r.end())
```

If a match is found, then you can access the starting and ending position by `.start` and `.end` methods.  You can calculate the repetition using them.

If you need to find all matches in the sequence, then you can use `re.finditer`, which gives you match objects iteratively.

You can loop over target patterns and find the longest one.

Answer (score 1):

Here using two for loops; one to grab each string (sequence) from `strs`, and the other to iterate over our `dna` strand to match each string from `strs` against it, and a while loop is used if a match was found to keep looking for consecutive (back2back) matches. (Added inline comments to give brief explanations on each step)

```
dna = 'AAGGTAAGTTTAGAATATAAAAGGTGAGTTAAATAGAATAGGTTAAAATTAAAGGAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCTATCTATCTATCTATCTATCAGAAAAGAGTAAATAGTTAAAGAGTAAGATATTGAATAGATCTAATGGAAAATATTGTTGGGGAAAGGAGGGATAGAAGG'
strs = ['AGATC', 'AATG', 'TATC']


def seq_finder(sequence, dna):
    start = 0  # Will allow us to skip scanned sequences
    counter = [0] * len(sequence)  # Create a list of zeros to store sequence occurrences
    for idx, seq in enumerate(sequence):  # Iterate over every entry in our sequence "strs"
        k = len(seq)
        holder = 0  # A temporarily holder that will store #occurrences of *consecutive* sequences
        for i in range(start, len(dna)):  # For each sequence, iterate over our "dna" strand
            if dna[i:i+k] == strs[idx]:  # If match is found:
                holder += 1  # Increment our holder by 1
                while dna[i:i+k] == dna[i+k:i+k*2]:  # If our match has an identical match ahead (consecutively):
                    holder += 1  # Increment our holder by 1
                    i += k  # Start the next list indexing from our new match
                    start = i + 1  # To skip repetitive iterations over same matches
                if holder > counter[idx]:
                    counter[idx] = holder  # Only replace counter if new holder > old holder
                holder = 0  # Reset the holder when we existed our of our while loop (finished finding consecutives)
    return counter
```